# Constant drop in connection with two chained routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, gateway

I have a [Cisco DPC3829](http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/modem_DPC3829.html) gateway and a [TP-Link TL-WR841N](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR841N.html) router connected to the gateway in order to separate the router network and use the gateway as a guest network. This way, I can create a homegroup within the router and nobody connected to the guest can access the homegroup.

However, those connected to the router are constantly experiencing drops in connection, even when connected via Ethernet. My computer states:

> The DNS Server is not responding.

I’ve tried almost every configuration possible but no matter what, the router will randomly drop Internet connection, even with a different router. I tried pre-assigning the router a DHCP IP Address.

Setting up a guest network in the gateway is not an option because the guest will have access to all devices connected to it, which is why I have a second router.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is your gateway connected to the router through the "WAN" port of the router?

Comment: Yes, the WAN port of the router connects to one of the ports in the gateway. My computers and devices are connected to the LAN port of the router.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the IP address of the router is on a different subnet than that of the gateway.

The way that I’m imaginating your connection is that the gateway has a static IP address (like `192.168.1.1`) and is handling DHCP for devices connected to it. The router has a different LAN static IP (like `192.168.2.1`). The router should be getting it's WAN IP from the gateway (like `192.168.1.100`).

Any devices that connect to the router should have the following (when you do an "ipconfig /all" in DOS box):

- **IP address:** `192.168.2.x`
- **Gateway address:** `192.168.2.1`
- **DHCP address:** `192.168.2.1`
- **DNS address:** `192.168.2.1`

Comment: Devices connected to thw router should have the dns of the router. The router should then uses the dns of gateway to get out. Try "tracert www.google.com" in a DOS box. This will display all the IP that the packets traveled.  The first couple of IP should show your network.